# Ruby - how to intercept a block and modify it before eval-ing or yield-ing it?

Tags: ruby

I have been thinking about blocks in Ruby.

Please consider this code:

```
div {
  h2 'Hello world!'
  drag
}
```

This calls the method `div()`, and passes a block to it.

With yield I can evaluate the block.

`h2()` is also a method, and so is `drag()`.

Now the thing is - `h2()` is defined in a module, which
is included. `drag()` on the other hand resides on an
object and also needs some additional information.

I can provide this at run-time, but not at call-time.

In other words, I need to be able to "intercept" 
`drag()`, change it, and then call that method 
on another object.

Is there a way to evaluate `yield()` line by line
or some other way? I don't have to call yield
yet, it would also be possible to get this
code as string, modify `drag()`, and then 
`eval()` on it (although this sounds ugly, I
just need to have this available anyway
no mater how).

Comment: so you want to implement something like before and after hooks? defining hooks is not that difficult of a concept but I need to understand the problem at a deeper level before answering. What is the current output and what is the desired output

Comment: Check the gem https://github.com/ngty/sourcify

Comment: What do you mean you want to change it? If you receive it as a block, there's nothing you can do, as a block is not an object. You could `yield` a different block, but in that case there's no point passing any block.  You could convert it to a `Proc` as a received parameter, but how would you propose to "look into it" to see what needs to be changed?

Comment: Sounds like you want some sort of proxy object

Comment: This (seems - I'm not totally sure on what you're asking) like a time to use `instance_eval` to evaluate the block in the context of the object that implements `drag`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it seems that you're looking for the [.tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method. Tap allows you to access intermediate results within a method chain. Of course, this would require you to restructure how this is set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of do this with `instance_eval` and a proxy object.

The general idea would be something like this:

```
class DSLProxyObject
  def initialize(proxied_object)
    @target = proxied_object
  end

  def drag
    # Do some stuff
    @target.drag
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    @target.send(method, *args, &block)
  end
end

DSLProxyObject.new(target_object).instance_eval(&block)
```

You could implement each of your DSL's methods, perform whatever modifications you need to when a method is called, and then call what you need to on the underlying object to make the DSL resolve.

It's difficult to answer your question completely without a less general example, but the general idea is that you would create an object context that has the information you need and which wraps the underlying DSL, then evaluate the DSL block in that context, which would let you intercept and modify individual calls on a per-usage basis.